# R Separate Results from Code

Tags: r

I am using R or starting to use R. I did some script using for loops, if... and I am happy with the results.

Now the issue I have is that in the console I would have all the line of codes (around 150 lines) when really I am just interested in 4 lines, my results.

Is there anyway to clean the console to see only some requested lines? and not all of the codes? If not I am thinking about saving them in a csv file and access the csv file to see the results of the script but it is not really efficient.

Thanks in advance

Xavier

Comment: Some questions : What editor do you use? How do you send the lines to R? Do you work with Rterm or Rgui? You'll have to be more specific on that one.

Answer (score 7):

I expect this to depend on how your 'results' are in the console, and whether all the rest is truly 'code'. Are these 4 lines the result of cat/print statements? Then you could look at `?sink` to send the results to a file.

Another option is to store these results in a variable (e.g. a list), and at the end of all your calculations, print this list. after that it should be easy to do the separation.

Comment: I agree with Nick's answer - If you will need the same sort of result on multiple future occasions, you should really have your code buffer the relevant information in a variable. If you just want a quick and dirty one-off solution, the suggestion to use sink is right - then you can just run 'grep' or any search tool on the resulting file.

Answer (score 4):

You are writing code in a script editor and not in the console right? Another option would be to use `source()` on the script which will run the entire script but won't show in the console (only the output). RStudio (which I strongly recommend you use for R; http://rstudio.org/) has a "source this file" button or something like that.

But more importantly, getting R to clearly return the results is a big part of learning how to program in R. You want your scripts to be clear for others as well! Some solutions would be to make some code chunks a `function`  or as Nick suggested storing results in a `list`.

Answer (score 3):

For me, I would put your code into a function, which would effectively hide the code from the console as it is run, and store the results of the code into a variable and then save that to a file

```
foo <- function(x) {
    result<-0
    for(i in 1:length(x)){
        result<-result+x[i]
    }
    return(result)
}

bar <- foo(x=c(2,3,4,5,4,3,2,3,4,5))
write.csv(bar, "resultfile.csv")
```